# Using nsExec to installing INF file. Log shows return value -10

Tags: nsis

I'm working on an installer that installs an inf file. I'm using the nsExec plugin.

My log is giving Return value: -10. What does a -10 error mean here? IF I enter the wrong path I can an expected value like "error" but I don't understand this -10 return value.

```
nsExec::ExecToStack '"My.exe" /a "The.inf"'      
    Pop $0 # return value/error/timeout
    Pop $1 # printed text, up to ${NSIS_MAX_STRLEN}
    DetailPrint '"My.exe" /a "The.inf"' 
    DetailPrint ""
    DetailPrint "       Return value: $0"
    DetailPrint  ""
```

If I do the example given in [the nsExec plugin page](https://nsis.sourceforge.io/NsExec_plug-in), I get a return value of 0. So I assume -10 is an error of some kind, but not one I've encountered thus far.

The exe and inf files are custom to org.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any number is the exit code from the process. -10 is the exit code of My.exe.

Only My.exe knows what -10 means. A negative number might be a HRESULT error code.

Comment: It was a custom error code from within my.exe, your answer made me check!